# Storing raw cranberry

Tags: cranberries

I want to be able to use chopped raw cranberries instead of sweetened dried cranberries in oatmeal and yogurt year round. Can I chop raw cranberries and then store in the freezer?

Answer (score 3):

According to the [Cranberry Institute:](http://www.cranberryinstitute.org/cranfacts/faq.htm)

> Yes. In fact cranberries freeze very well either whole or sliced.
>   Sealed in an airtight container frozen cranberries will keep for
>   nearly a year.

Personal experience bears this out as well, with unsweetened cranberry dressing (fresh cranberries and orange zest, zapped in a food processor. Thaw, add sugar to one batch for those who like it traditional, and splenda to the other for dieters and diabetics.)